# Error 1062 duplicate entry key 1 for key primary

Tags: mysql, duplication

I have a problem when I try to import data

```
create table song (
    artist_id int not null,
    album_id int not null,
    song_name varchar(75),
    tracknum int not null,
    primary key (artist_id, album_id, tracknum),
    foreign key (artist_id) references artist(artist_id)
        on delete restrict
        on update cascade,
    foreign key (album_id) references album(album_id)
        on delete restrict
        on update cascade
    );
```

How do I fix the duplicate value? I am trying to upload a data dump from files. It is working for all the tables except this one.

Comment: the error was due to the primary key and columns being out of order seems to work when I fixed that

Comment: This is not clear. Please clarify via edits, not comments. If you solved this, please consider posting an answer. For code questions please give a [mre]. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit your structure, remove both PRIMARY KEY definition and FOREIGN KEYS definitions. Or, if the table is now empty, simply drop it and re-create without PK and FKs.
2. Import your data.
3. Execute

   ```
   ALTER TABLE song ADD COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
   ```
4. Execute

   ```
   SELECT song.*
   FROM song 
   NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT artist_id, album_id, tracknum
                  FROM song
                  GROUP BY artist_id, album_id, tracknum
                  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) dups
   ORDER BY artist_id, album_id, tracknum;
   ```

   You will see ALL duplicates.

   Check `id` values of excess row and remove them:

   ```
   DELETE FROM song
   WHERE id IN ({duplicates ids list})
   ```

   Of course if you find 2 duplicated rows you must delete only one of them.
5. Remove `id` column

   ```
   ALTER TABLE song DROP COLUMN id;
   ```
6. Restore primary key and foreign keys

   ```
   ALTER TABLE song ADD primary key (artist_id, album_id, tracknum);
   ALTER TABLE song ADD  foreign key (artist_id) references artist(artist_id)
           on delete restrict
           on update cascade;
   ALTER TABLE song ADD foreign key (album_id) references album(album_id)
           on delete restrict
           on update cascade;
   ```

   If some FK creation fails gather the values which have no matching values in reference table and create them then repeat FK creation.